# Can I select an element which has a child that is empty?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an element whose child with a specific class name is empty. No js no jquery, with just simple css3.

So in this case result should select li#x since the div element with the 'value' class is empty but I can't figure it out. Is this possible?

```
<li id="m">
   <div class="key">Item1</div>
   <div class="value">description</div>
</li>
<li id="x">
  <div class="key">Item2</div>
  <div class="value"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: That's not possible since there is no way to select a parent element. There is an `:empty` pseudo class though.

Comment: really? i had never heard of `:empty` before

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty there is no parent selector in CSS so while you can detect the empty child, you can't target the parent based on that

Comment: just as suspected. thanks for confirming!